# scat distribution family in mgcv R package

Tags: r, mgcv

In fitting generalized Additive Models (GAMs) to my simulated data, I find that the data produce QQ plots with very heavy tails.

To get around this, I am using the 'scat' distribution family in the 'mgcv' R package, which works like a charm.

I am also looking to compare with a Shape-Constrained Additive Model (SCAM) via the 'scam' R package.

Since SCAMs are a somewhat relatively new innovation, I am appealing to anyone who may have written some R code to implement 'scat' for SCAMs, since there is nothing in existing documentation to support such analysis.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: A SCAM is a wide collection of models. You need to explain exactly which model you are fitting as there are options for fitting shape constrained models with `gam`. If you can't fit it with `gam` then you're probably out of luck as Simon & co have only developed methods for these extended-family or general smooth models by maximum likelhood and *scam* only estimates smoothness parameters via GCV.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I realize the limitation of the scam package since it is quite new, but i think using mono.con in mgcv may be cumbersome for the number of simulated datasets I would like to fit (I haven't tried the approach yet). In scam, I'm leaning toward bs = "micv" since my data exhibit both monotonicity and concavity. this basis function will be compared to both adaptive splines (which are based on P-splines by default), so they are directly comparable to SCAMs (which are based on Eilers and Marx (1996) finite difference P-splines)